# What does this mean in Bootstrap 3 docs?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In this page on the Bootstrap 3 documentation regarding the grid system (in the grid options table):
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

It says the following:
Grid behaviour: Horizontal at all times, Collapsed to start, horizontal above breakpoints

Can someone please explain what this means, perhaps even with an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**"Horizontal at all times"** applies to extra small column (`.col-xs`):

- No matter what screen size, even with small screen (on phone for example) the columns will always be horizontal (i.e stay on the same row), as long as there is enough room in the grid (remember the 12 column grid, col-xs-6 + col-xs-6 will fit in that row; adding another column will go on underneath that first row). See example below in a ~ 900 x 768 screen size:

[image: Example of the col-xs-* in a ~ 900 x 768 browser screen size]

Code Sample:

```
<div class="row show-grid"> 
 <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div> 
 <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
 <div class="col-xs-3">.col-xs-3</div>
</div>
```

**"Collapsed to start, horizontal above breakpoints"** applies to small (`sm`), medium (`md`) and large (`lg`) column classes:

- It means that the columns will be horizontal if the screen is large enough. But if the screen is smaller than a pre-define "breakpoint" the columns becomes vertical.

You can try it on the examples in the documentation (on your link) by reducing your browser width.

Answer (score 2):

It's the worst definition in the history!

Definition:

```
Collapsed to start
```

what they want to say is

> column width 12/12

Definition:

```
horizontal above breakpoints
```

what they want to say is

> when the screen reaches a certain width (breakpoint) columns become x/12 percentages according to classes used per column otherwise, remains 12/12

What they don't say is that they implement a waterfall -aka cascading- model of ccs media queries:

1. first all columns are defined as 12/12 (collapsed or mobile-first approach)
2. then, media queries follow from smaller to higher breakpoints:

*is the screen small? apply rules for small screens*

*is the screen medium? apply rules for medium screens*

*is the screen large? apply rules for large screens*

If in your implementation of such a grid system you don't define an upper limit in each and every query then for a large screen **ALL** queries will apply with the winner be the last (a waterfall model)!

Of course in such a "nonsense(?)" - of no upper limits- the next query should overwrite the rules of it's ancestor meaning endless duplicate code!

In bootstrap there is **no upper limit** in it's queries so writing sth like:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6"></div>
```

we can see 2 equal columns in phones (<768) and 2 stacked columns in small (>768) devices and beyond.

But why? Because there is a class `col-sm-8` for the first column but for the missing rule in the second one the waterfall model has already applied width 6/12! (follow the questions of media queries above: a small screen is certainly extra small, a medium is certainly extra small and small etc.).

On the other hand if the developer **had** implemented queries in both sizes (upper & lower) the column No.2 would be undefined without proper class and that means would remain 12/12 in the mobile-first approach!

Bottom line, designers have to give fewer classes in their grids when no-upper limits exist in media queries but the behavior is not that intuitive!

Answer (score 1):

It means if you use the col-xs classes, your grid will be horizontal on all screens, while if you use the col-sm, col-md, col-lg classes, it will be horizontal on screen widths greater than 768px,992px,1170px respectively, else they will be collapsed.

As an example, look at [Example: Stacked-to-horizontal](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic) on the same page and resize your browser. The grid uses the col-md class. You'll notice that the grid stays horizontal as long as the viewport width is >992px, below which it is collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

You are not the only one who is confused: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9365

I also find this a bit confusing. In my view the best way to figure out how the grid system works is by looking at the example directly below the table and play around with resizing the browser. Ideally you want to also take a look at this example on your smartphone, if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer chosen is badly stated. And the Bootstrap 3 documentation regarding the grid system is also a bit confusing the way it is stated. So:

- **"Horizontal at all times" for extra small columns (col-xs-) :** Means that if the col-xs- class is used then the columns will be
  placed in one row, one next to the other no matter the size of the
  screen or the device.
- **"Collapsed to start, horizontal above breakpoints" for the rest of the classes (sm,md,lg):** Means that if e.g. the col-md- class is used, then if the size of the screen is smaller than 992px (the lower limit of the md class) the columns will be placed one below the other (as if they were rows). If the size of the screen is greater than 992px then they will be placed in one row, one next to the other.

The key point here is understanding that **"horizontal"** refers to the way the columns are positioned inside the `<row>` element, **NOT** their shape.